# How to make the Cancel request processing work

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I made a component Pul which makes a request to the server and processes it.
[Pul](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-heisenberg-3ldj2)

But I want to make a separate ProcessingRequest class for throwing and processing.[Pul + ProcessingRequest](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-5z6wb)

Why fetch works only once and throws an error?

```
class ProcessingRequest {
  abortController: AbortController = new AbortController();

  async ServerRequest(endURL: string) {
    try {
      console.log(this.abortController);
      const Res = await fetch(`${endURL}`, {
        signal: this.abortController.signal
      });
      const Product = await Res.json();
      if (!Res.ok || !Product) {
        throw new Error("Page Not Found 404");
      }
      return Product;
    } catch (error) {
      return error.name !== "AbortError" ? `${error.message}` : "";
    }
  }

  Abort() {
    this.abortController.abort();
  }
}

export default new ProcessingRequest();
```

Comment: So what is the question here? What is the desired behavior that isn't working?